# Have there been any experiments that have demonstrated a quantum error correcting code?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Has quantum error correction been demonstrated? I know that classical error correction has been demonstrated by [1], they correct a single bit flip error, but has anyone been able to detect and correct both bitflip and phase errors?

[1]http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v432/n7017/full/nature03074.html

Comment: Have you read this section and considered the links therein? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction#Experimental_realization